# Laravel routing strange behavior

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a single domain/subdomain project. In order to see the event by slug, I made this route:

```
Route::prefix('events')->namespace('Content\Controller')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'EventController@getIndex')->name('event.index');
    Route::get('{slug}', 'EventController@getView')->name('event.show');
    Route::get('{slug}/edit', 'EventController@getEdit')->name('event.edit');
    Route::post('load-more-ajax/{region?}', 'EventController@postLoadMoreAjax');
    Route::any('sorted-ajax/{region?}', 'EventController@anySortedAjax');
    Route::get('category/{category_slug}/{subcategory_slug?}', 'EventController@getCategory');
});
```

After my page didn't load correctly, I did a dump in the controller:

```
public function getView($slug)
{
    return $slug;
}
```

To get to the route I am using this URL: `https://example.com/events/slug-example`.

The problem is that the route is being hit as I see the response when I change it, but I am not getting the slug, instead I am getting `Region` object back.

If I do this:

```
public function getView($region, $slug)
{
    return $slug;
}
```

Then I get the slug back. But I have no idea how is this possible, and how could I do it (I came as another dev on the existing project).

I tried commenting out all the middleware and it is still the same. How can I even make something fill the method if I didn't explicitly say it?

**EDIT**

I noticed there is binding going on in routes file:

```
Route::bind('region', function ($value) {
    ...
});
```

Now if I `dd($value)` I get the variable back. How is this value filled? From where could it be forwarded?

Comment: It's filled when you have `{region}` in url but you claim you are not and you are hitting `{slug}` routeso it's impossible that you have region for this route.

Comment: I do! I forgot to add it in the question...instead of `example.com` I'm hitting `{region}.example.com`. That one is read first. Thanks

Comment: So this is correct behaviour. If you have region as parameter, you need to use this parameter in controller method

Comment: Update answer so I can accept it

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking quickly it should work, but maybe you was verifying other url.

Make sure you put:

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'EventController@getView')->name('event.show');
Route::get('{slug}/edit', 'EventController@getEdit')->name('event.edit');
```

routes at the end of routes you showed.

**EDIT**

If you think that's not the case and you don't have your routes cached you should run:

```
php artisan route:list
```

to verify your routes.

**EDIT2**

After explaining by OPs in comment, domain used for accessing site is:

```
{region}.example.com
```

So having `$region` in controller as 1st parameter is correct behaviour because of route model binding and other route parameters will be 2nd, 3rd and so on.

Comment: The route is being hit, so order doesn't really matter now.

Comment: Order is important because `sorted-ajax` url will go into `EventController@getView` now. For sure you shouldn't get any region in your `getView` so as I said make sure you are using realy valid urls and you go into valid controller method. Also you might need to run `php artisan route:clear` if you cached them before.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the issue here, I am hitting the right route.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Route::prefix('events')->namespace('Content\Controller')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'EventController@getIndex')->name('event.index');
    Route::get('{slug}', 'EventController@getView')->name('event.show');
    Route::get('{slug}/edit', 'EventController@getEdit')->name('event.edit');
    Route::post('load-more-ajax/{region?}', 'EventController@postLoadMoreAjax');
    Route::any('sorted-ajax/{region?}', 'EventController@anySortedAjax');
    Route::get('category/{category_slug}/{subcategory_slug?}', 'EventController@getCategory');
});
```

try

```
Route::prefix('events')->namespace('Content\Controller')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'EventController@getIndex')->name('event.index');
    Route::post('load-more-ajax/{region?}', 'EventController@postLoadMoreAjax');
    Route::any('sorted-ajax/{region?}', 'EventController@anySortedAjax');
    Route::get('category/{category_slug}/{subcategory_slug?}', 'EventController@getCategory');
    Route::get('{slug}', 'EventController@getView')->name('event.show');
    Route::get('{slug}/edit', 'EventController@getEdit')->name('event.edit');
});
```